# How to evaluate the integral $\int_0^t\frac{xe^x}{1+e^x}\,dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, derivatives

$$I=\int_0^t\frac{xe^x}{1+e^x}\,dx$$

I tried this method to solve this integral by using an operator y, so the integral could be formed as :
$$I(y)=\int_0^t\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\ln{(1+e^{y x})}\,dx$$
Then we can write it as :
$$I(y)=\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\int_0^t\ln{(1+e^{y x})}\,dx$$
We calculate the integral of $$\int_0^t\ln(1+e^{yx})\,dx$$
It would give us as we substitute $$u=e^{yx}$$ then
we have  $$du=ye^{yx}dx$$ so $$dx=\frac{du}{yu}$$
$$\frac{1}{y}\int_1^{e^{yt}}\frac{\ln(1+u)}{u}\,du$$
We substitute $$v=-u$$
$$dv=-du$$
$$-\frac{1}{y}\int_1^{e^{yt}}\frac{\ln(1-v)}{v}\,dv=-\frac{1}{y}\int_0^{e^{yt}}\frac{\ln(1-v)}{v}\,dv-\frac{1}{y}\pi^2\frac{1}{6}$$
Then we get
$$\frac{1}{y}\operatorname{Li}_2(-e^{yt})-\frac{1}{y}\pi^2\frac{1}{6}$$
Intering the partial derivative
$$I(y)=\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(\frac{1}{y}\operatorname{Li}_2(-e^{yt})-\frac{1}{y}\pi^2\frac{1}{6})$$

Comment: What’s the context for this problem/where did you find it? These kind of integrals typically result in “polylogarithm” functions appearing in the answer. To avoid worrying about that, I would recommend trying to write the integrand in terms of a Taylor series, then integrating term-wise.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integral+ln%281%2Be%5Ex%29dx

Comment: Using integration by parts with $f=\ln(1+e^x)$, we have $I=\int xf'=xf-\int f$. To find $\int f=\int\ln(1+e^x)\,dx$, substituting $u=-e^x$ gives $\int f=\int\frac{\ln(1-u)}u\,du=-\text{Li}_2(u)$, where Li$_2$ is the [dilogarithm function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spence%27s_function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^t\frac{xe^x}{1+e^x}dx&=\int_0^t\frac{x}{1+e^{-x}}dx\\
&=\int_0^t\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^nxe^{-nx} dx\\
&=\int_0^t\left(x+\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^nxe^{-nx}\right)dx\\
&=\frac{t^2}2+\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\int_0^t xe^{-nx}dx\\
&=\frac{t^2}2+\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\left(\left.-\frac1nxe^{-nx}\right\vert_0^t+\frac1n\int_0^t e^{-nx}dx\right)\\
&\stackrel{\large\color{red}{IBP}}{=}\frac{t^2}2+\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n}\left(-\frac1n te^{-nt}-\left[\frac1{n^2}e^{-nx}\right]_0^t\right)\\
&=\frac{t^2}2+\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n+1}\left(\frac1n te^{-nt}+\frac1{n^2}e^{-nt}-\frac1{n^2}\right)\\
&=\frac{t^2}2+t\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}(e^{-t})^n-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-e^{-t})^n}{n^2}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n^2}\\
&=\frac{t^2}2+t\ln(1+e^{-t})-\text{Li}_2(-e^{-t})+\text{Li}_2(-1)\\
&=-\frac{t^2}2+t\ln(1+e^{t})-\text{Li}_2(-e^{-t})-\frac{\pi^2}{12}\\
&\stackrel{\large*}{=}t\ln(1+e^{t})+\text{Li}_2(-e^{t})+\frac{\pi^2}{12}
\end{align}$$

$\color{red}{IBP}$: Integration by parts

$\text{Li}_2(s):$ Dilogarithm

$*: \text{Li}_2(z)+\text{Li}_2(z^{-1})=-\frac{\pi^2}{6}-\frac{\ln^2(-z)}{2}$

Answer (score 7):

$$
\begin{aligned}
I & =\int \frac{x e^x}{1+e^x} d x \quad \textrm{ via IBP} \\
& =\int x d\left[\ln \left(1+e^x\right)\right] \\
& =x \ln \left(1+e^x\right)-\int \ln \left(1+e^x\right) d x\\& 
=x \ln \left(1+e^x\right)+\operatorname{Li}_2\left(-e^x\right) +C\quad \textrm{ via } y=e^{-x}
\end{aligned}
$$

Hence we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^t \frac{x e^x}{1+e^x} d x= & t \ln \left(1+e^t\right)+ \operatorname{Li}_2\left(-e^t\right)-\operatorname{Li}_2(-1) \\
= & t \ln \left(1+e^t\right)+ \operatorname{Li}_2\left(-e^t\right)+\frac{\pi^2}{12}
\end{aligned}
$$

Answer (score 0):

$$I=\int_0^t\frac{xe^x}{1+e^x}\,dx$$

I tried this method to solve this integral by using an operator $y$, so the integral could be formed as :
$$I(y)=\int_0^t\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\ln{(1+e^{y x})}\,dx$$
Then we can write it as :
$$I(y)=\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\int_0^t\ln{(1+e^{y x})}\,dx$$
We calculate the integral of $$\int_0^t\ln(1+e^{yx})\,dx$$
Using integration by parts we get
$$\int_0^t\ln(1+e^{yx})\,dx=x\ln(1+e^{yx})\rvert_0^t-y\int_0^t\frac{xe^{yx}}{1+e^{yx}}\,dx$$
$$y\int_0^t\frac{xe^{yx}}{1+e^{yx}}dx=x\ln(1+e^{yx})\rvert_0^t-\int_0^t\ln(1+e^{yx})\,dx$$
We put $$y=1$$
Then we have:
$$\int_0^t\frac{xe^{x}}{1+e^{x}}dx=x\ln(1+e^{x})\rvert_0^t-\int_0^t\ln(1+e^{x})\,dx$$
$$\int_0^t\frac{xe^{x}}{1+e^{x}}dx=t\ln(1+e^{t})-\int_0^t\ln(1+e^{x})\,dx$$
The series expansion of
$$ln(1-u)=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{u^n}{n}$$
$$\int_0^t\ln(1-(-e^{x}))\,dx=-\int_0^t\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n{e^x}^n}{n}\,dx=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n}\int_0^t e^{xn}dx$$
We get
$$-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n}\int_0^t e^{xn}dx=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}e^{xn}\rvert_0^t$$
$$-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}e^{xn}\rvert_0^t=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}(e^{nt}-1)$$
$$-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}(e^{nt}-1)=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}e^{nt}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}$$
$$\int_0^t\ln(1-(-e^{x}))\,dx=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}e^{nt}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}$$
$$\int_0^t\ln(1-(-e^{x}))\,dx=-Li_2(-e^{t})-\frac{\pi^2}{12}$$
$$\int_0^t\frac{xe^{x}}{1+e^{x}}dx=t\ln(1+e^{t})-(-Li_2(-e^{t})-\frac{\pi^2}{12})$$
The solution is:
$$\int_0^t\frac{xe^{x}}{1+e^{x}}dx=t\ln(1+e^{t})+Li_2(-e^{t})+\frac{\pi^2}{12}$$

Comment: Is $+Li_2(-1)$ missing?